# $x^6+x^3+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have been trying to prove that $x^6+x^3+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (or $\mathbb{Z}$ since by Gauss' Lemma is the same), but I can't. Any idea of how to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: Let $y=x-1$, and apply Eisenstein's criterion for $p=3$.

Comment: Thanks! How did you figure out that that substitution would work?

Comment: HINT:$f(x)=g(x)h(x)\implies f(x+a)=g(x+a)h(x+a),\forall a\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @FranciscoMartínez The inspiration is to modify the proof that $x^p + x^{p-1} + \ldots + x +1$ is irreducible. If have you seen that one before, this seems a natural thing to do here. If you haven't, now you have a hint on how to do that problem :)

Answer (score 5):

It's the $9$-th cyclotomic polynomial, and all cyclotomic polynomials are irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

The generalised form of Cohn's criterion also works: all of the coefficients are non-negative and smaller than $2$, and $P(2) = 73$ is prime.