# Determine multiple roots of $x^6+x^3+1$ over different fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This is a follow up to a question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551946/reducibility-of-x6x31-over-various-fields).

For ease of understanding, I'll repeat some material. I want now to determine the irreducible factors of the polynomial $f(x)=x^6+x^3+1$ over the fields $\mathbb{F}_n$ for $n=2,3,19$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Next Step** I now want to determine for which fields the irreducible factors have a repeated root.

**Thoughts** If I consider the formal derivative of $f$, $Df$, then any repeated roots of $f$ should also be roots of $Df(x)=6x^5+3x^2=3(2x^5+x^2)$. Is this now a case of seeing whether $3(2x^5+x^2)$ is reducible in each of these fields and if its has roots in these fields, whether they match up with those of $f$?

Comment: Use einsenstein's criterion for $n=2$

Comment: The presence of repeated roots can be checked by finding the gcd of $f$ and $Df$ by using Euclid's algorithm. Of course, as this $f(x)$ is the ninth cyclotomic polynomial, problems can (and will) occur only in characteristic three.

Comment: But, really, solving your other question settles this one probably faster than calculating that gcd.